# Page faults when 25% used physical memory

Tags: windows, memory

I am working on a console application that get a number of page faults even though the used physical memory is at 25%.  Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Physical memory is a precious resource, and it is very rarely left unused in a modern OS. Anything not actively used by a process will be recycled for cache/buffers. For instance, on my 2gig Linux box at home:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2058188    1905112     153076          0     176624    1530208
-/+ buffers/cache:     198280    1859908
Swap:      1052248          0    1052248
```

Note the `1905112` and `153076`. By this measure, my physical memory is almost fully committed. Yet, once you eliminate buffers/cache on the next line, it shows almost 1.8gig free and only 200meg used.

Your page faults are simply the OS dumping some of those caches/buffers to make room for your application's needs.